# Incremental count

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, window-functions, lead

I have a table with a list of Customer Numbers and Order Dates and want to add a count against each Customer number, restarting from 1 each time the customer number changes, I've sorted the Table into Customer then Date order, and need to add an order count column.

```
CASE WHEN 'Customer Number' on This row = 'Customer Number' on Previous Row then ( Count = Count on Previous Row + 1 ) 
Else Count = 1
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Customer and Dates in Customer then Date order:

```
Customer    Date      Count
0001        01/05/18  1 
0001        02/05/18  2
0001        03/05/18  3
0002        03/05/18  1  <- back to one here as Customer changed
0002        04/05/18  2
0003        05/05/18  1  <- back to one again
```

I've just tried `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ) as COUNT` but it doesn't seem to be starting from 1 for some reason when the Customer changes

Comment: Can you add some data, in tabular format, to your question?  Your logic is not entirely clear (at least not to me).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you want, but "*to add a count against each Customer number, restarting from 1 each time the customer number changes*" sounds as if you simply want:

```
count(*) over (partition by customer_number)
```

or maybe that should be the count "up-to" the date of the row:

```
count(*) over (partition by customer_number order by order_date)
```

Comment: Hi, apologies if I've not explain it very well :-)   basically need to do something like this...                                                                                                                     Cust  Date       Count
0001  01/02/18   1
0001  02/02/18   2
0001  03/02/18   3
0002  05/03/18   1
0002  06/03/18   2
0003  01/02/18   1

Comment: @Gavin: do **not** explain that in comments. [**EDIT**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50946811/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you just want [an analytic `row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html) call:

```
select customer_number,
  order_date,
  row_number() over (partition by customer_number order by order_date) as num
from your_table
order by customer_number,
  order_date
```

Using an [analytic count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COUNT.html) also works, as @horse_with_no_name suggested:

```
  count(*) over (partition by customer_number order by order_date) as num
```

Quick demo showing both, with your sample data in a CTE:

```
with your_table (customer_number, order_date) as (
            select '0001', date '2018-05-01' from dual
  union all select '0001', date '2018-05-03' from dual
  union all select '0001', date '2018-05-02' from dual
  union all select '0002', date '2018-05-03' from dual
  union all select '0002', date '2018-05-04' from dual
  union all select '0003', date '2018-05-05' from dual
)
select customer_number,
  order_date,
  row_number() over (partition by customer_number order by order_date) as num1,
  count(*) over (partition by customer_number order by order_date) as num2
from your_table
order by customer_number,
  order_date
/

CUST ORDER_DATE       NUM1       NUM2
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
0001 2018-05-01          1          1
0001 2018-05-02          2          2
0001 2018-05-03          3          3
0002 2018-05-03          1          1
0002 2018-05-04          2          2
0003 2018-05-05          1          1
```